# Why this error comes in struts2 org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'template.vm'

Tags: web-applications, struts2, velocity

I am using Apache Velocity template engine for my web application html email utility.

But the major problem i am facing is the resource path.
I am using struts2 for my web application(Struts2 maven arch.. project)
& i have created folder templates & inside of it i have created email.vm file which is template so i moved templates folder to resource (So when war will be created it will go to WEB-INF/classes folder)

& in my utility class i am trying to get the template as follow:

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
            ve.init();
     VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
                context.put("petList", list);

                log.info("Context added");

                /*
                 *   get the Template  
                 */
                Template t = ve.getTemplate("email.vm" );
                log.info("Got Template");


                /*
                 *  now render the template into a Writer, here 
                 *  a StringWriter 
                 */
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                t.merge( context, writer );
```

So i am getting error 
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'template.vm'

I gone through every related question on this in stackoverflow & applied the solution but still no luck 
So can somebody tell me whats wrong i am doing or missing ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/developer-guide.html#resourceloaders and this http://tech--help.blogspot.com/2010/02/solved-apache-velocity-how-to-load.html. And use google next time.

Comment: after careful reading of 1 hour i came to know how it works.
Thanks for your answer